# iPhone table scroll losses cell data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

Since updating this morning to IOS 4.3.3 I have a problem with the table data.
The rows have 2 cell items with text on it.
The second cell item us updated after a selection. And are updated in viewWillAppear.
That works ok.

But after scrolling the data from the screen and back in again it's gone....

The original cell2 values are replaced over the changed ones.

Any idea's, is this releated with the ios updated?

Comment: Add your code please. It looks like something wrong with dequeueing cell.

Comment: Either that or in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method you're using the old data, not the new ? (the scroll off the top of the app will cause the cell to be reloaded)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responces.

I had to load the new data again in the viewWillAppear and not only in the viewDidLoad.
Strange thing is that it worked ok before 4.3.3